# Django + Azure: How to implement a 301 redirect from naked to www domain

Tags: django, azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service

I am running Django app on Microsoft Azure and need to 301 redirect all traffic to a single secure www domain i.e.

From:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com 
http://www.example.com
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com
```

I assume I need to set up a redirect with a server configuration file but I'm new to Azure and not sure how to go about it. The site is running on Linux.

In addition, I have set up https only so http requests are currently directed to https.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which platform you use, linux or windows?

Comment: Jason, we are using Linux platform

Comment: You can try Doris's suggestions, and you also can try to add `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Django has **redirects app**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/

> Django comes with an optional redirects application. It lets you store
> redirects in a database and handles the redirecting for you. It uses
> the HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently by default.

2. There is a service named **Application Gateway** you could consider: [Redirect web traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-redirect-cli)
3. you could use [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) for redirecting traffic, but this would return http 302 rather than 301.

Comment: Thanks Doris. Your solution 3 is best for me and it can be improved as in my posted answer to use function HttpResponsePermanentRedirect to make it a 301

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with is very simple to implement and found at

[How to Make Django Redirect WWW to Your Bare Domain](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/03/02/how-to-make-django-redirect-www-to-your-bare-domain/)

In summary

1. Create a new middleware file in one of your apps (e.g. myapp)

   from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

   ```
    class WwwRedirectMiddleware:
        def __init__(self, get_response):
            self.get_response = get_response

        def __call__(self, request):
            host = request.get_host().partition(':')[0]
            if host == "www.example.com":
                return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(
                    "https://example.com" + request.path
                )
            else:
                return self.get_response(request)
   ```
2. Adjust your settings.py file for allowed hosts

   ALLOWED_HOSTS=[
   # ...
   "example.com",
   "www.example.com",
   # ...
   ]
3. Add the middleware reference as high as possible but after SecurityMiddleware

   MIDDLEWARE = [
   "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
   "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
   "myapp.middleware.WwwRedirectMiddleware",
   # ...
   ]